# webview_flutter plugin - some website cannot load some website

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webview

I developed an app using flutter. Right now I want to open a website from WebView and It worked but some websites are not loading inside webview. I'm not sure what I've done wrong, Hope someone can help me to solve this problem. Thank you in advance.

plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter/example

URL work: https://flutter.dev/

URL that is not working: https://belanjawan2021.treasury.gov.my/manfaat/index.php/bm/pemulih-bkc

**Error**

> Failed to validate the certificate chain, error:
> java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
> certification path not found.

[image]

```
  Widget webView() {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        WebView(
            onPageStarted: (String url) {
              setState(() {
                _showProgress = true;
              });
            },
            onPageFinished: (String url) {
              setState(() {
                _showProgress = false;
              });
            },
            initialUrl: widget.feed.url,
            onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError webviewerrr) {
              print("webview_flutter:" + webviewerrr.description);
            },
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onProgress: (int progress) {}),
        _showProgress
            ? Center(
                child: SizedBox(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                height: 200,
                width: 200,
              ))
            : Stack()
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: It is not necessary that you are making mistakes ? As u said that some websites are working fine and others aren't, this means they have some restrictions or are not well-designed for mobile. Additionally, you can share errors while visiting to those sites to have a clear view

Comment: @AliYarKhan I added an error message, I think it's related to the current problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well I facing this issue about 4 months back, and at that time I used the plugin which you are using. The problem was that I have not allowed javascript and local storage for the web view. I would recommend you to use [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) and allow javascript and local storage for the webview. It would work.